# Detecting bounced email in a gmail integration

Tags: email, gmail, gmail-api, email-bounces

We want to provide a Gmail integration to help users find out all bounced emails. What will be the best way to do it? A user sent an email to xxxx@thiswillbounce.com and then got back a bounced email from the email server. From the gmail API, we can see bunch of headers from the bounced email. Can we use these headers to detect this is a bounced email programmatically?

Bounced email's headers:

`{
        "name": "Subject",
         "value": "Undeliverable: Test Mail"
    },
    {
         "name": "From",
         "value": "Microsoft Outlook <MicrosoftExchange329e71ec88ae4615bbc36ab6ce41109e@outlook.com>"
    }
...`

Comment: I answered [**this question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30387743/how-to-tell-if-an-email-sent-via-gmail-rest-api-has-bounced/31461716#31461716) a while back. I'm not sure it's still the easiest way, but it might give you some inspiration.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Gmail Search to detected bounced emails and they mostly have mailer-daemon as the sender.

```
from:(mailer-daemon@google.com OR mailer-daemon@googlemail.com)
```

You can then parse the plain text part of the raw message to detect the original recipient where the message was sent to.

I also wrote a tutorial on [detecting bounced emails in Gmail](https://www.labnol.org/internet/gmail-bounced-email-report/29209/) with Google Scripts.

Comment: Thanks. How about bounced emails from outlook? I can see those emails have "mailed-by:nam02-bl2-obe.outbound.protection.outlook.com".